Is it possible to change compression settings of non-empty hypertable?
I'm curious what would happen in case I'll change the compression settings of certain hypertable which already have some data.
I'm not talking about compression policy (which is, as I understand, might be removed and (re)created again any time). I'm talking about settings like compress_orderby or compress_segmentby.
I.e. what would happen if, at some point, I decide to extend the list of columns to segment data by? Is it possible at all? And if yes, then what would happen with the chunks which were compressed already?

Not possible. It's hard to cover all the ground of user context and just guess and move the data around. I think if the changes are predictable, still need some extra background jobs to make the same data structure conformity. If you want to change it, create a new hypertable and move over, dropping the old one.

@jonatasdp, looks like it's possible after all (tried on v16). I.e. I was able to alter non-empty hypertable and change its compression settings. Query executed without any errors, but I'm not sure if it's actually working (or how exactly it's working). Is it possible that only new chunks (which wasn't compressed yet) would be compressed according to the new settings (and the compressed ones would stay intact)? Or it would try to recompress all the chunks according to the new settings? Or settings update query was successful, but effectively did nothing?

Is it possible that only new chunks (which wasn't compressed yet) would be compressed according to the new settings (and the compressed ones would stay intact)?
Yes. That's exactly how it works.
